# while runing the chatbot_ner API in python shell we are getting this error

Tags: python, python-2.7

> File "/home/swathi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 19, in 
>   "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>   ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Comment: `python -m pip install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

You should install required dependency
The most simply way is using pip
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

```
pip install numpy
```

or install all `sci-py` pack

via `pip`:

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

more details here: https://www.scipy.org/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install [`numpy`](https://www.numpy.org/) to run your program:

`pip install numpy`